# Sublime Text 3 with "Make" build system doesn't run the program

Tags: c++, makefile, sublimetext3, sublime-build

I am trying to build a C++ project in Sublime Text 3 on Linux. Normally I just swap to the terminal and run `make run` and it runs. However, I'm trying to streamline the process by running directly in Sublime. However, pressing Ctrl+Shift+B brings up only two options: Make and Make clean. Both of which will do the command according to my Makefile for the project. However, there is no Make run, so I can't directly run the project by pressing Ctrl+B. I hope someone can provide some insight into this!

Here is my Makefile:

```
BINARY := build/project
SRCS := $(shell find . -iname "*.cpp")
OBJS := $(addprefix build/,$(SRCS:.cpp=.o))

NEEDED_LIBS := 

CXX := g++ -flto
LD := $(CXX) $(addprefix libs/,$(NEEDED_LIBS))
override CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
override LDFLAGS += $(CXXFLAGS)

all:$(BINARY)

$(BINARY):$(OBJS) $(addprefix libs/,$(NEEDED_LIBS))
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

build/%.o:%.cpp
    $(CXX) -O2 -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

run:$(BINARY)
    @$(BINARY)
    
clean:
    rm -rf build/*
```

Answer (score 2):

The default build for this is `Makefile/Make.sublime-build`, which looks like this:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "make",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:\n]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${folder:${project_path:${file_path}}}",
    "selector": "source.makefile",
    "syntax": "Packages/Makefile/Make Output.sublime-syntax",
    "keyfiles": ["Makefile", "makefile"],

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Clean",
            "shell_cmd": "make clean"
        }
    ]
}
```

That is, by default it just runs `Make`, but it also has a variant named `Clean` that will run `make clean` as well. In particular, this points out that the list of commands is static and doesn't rely on the actual content of the Makefile in question.

What you can do is choose `Tools > Build System > New Build System` from the menu, which will create a new tab and provide a default build system. Select all of that content, and then replace it with a copy of the above so you have a duplicate of the base build system. Then, you can add in additional variants as needed. For example:

```json
    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Clean",
            "shell_cmd": "make clean"
        },
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "make run"
        }
    ]
```

Once you're done, save the file in the location Sublime defaults to (your `User` package) with a custom name, like `Custom Makefile.sublime-build` or such (the location and the extension are the important parts).

Once you've done that, you will see your build system appear in the menu under `Tools > Build System` with the name that you saved the file as. You can either select the build there to use it, or leave it set as automatic.

When you use <kbd>ctrl+shift+b</kbd> next, the options from this build system will appear in the list (if the build is set to automatic, you'll see the default options as well).